# How can I set a ViewModels property to be a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am coding a `MVC 5` internet application and I have a question in regards to serializing a `ViewModel` property to a `JSON object`:

Here is an example `ViewModel`:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string exampleValue { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a `Create View`, how can I `serialize` the `exampleValue` property to be a `JSON object`, such that when the `[HttpPost]` `Create ActionResult` receives the object, the `exampleValue` is a `JSON object`?

I am wanting to be able to perform validation on the `ViewModel` with the `ModelState.IsValid` code, and then return the `ViewModel` back to the `View` if the `ViewModel` is not in a valid state, just like any other `[HttpPost]` function.

I have written the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "https://**url**/Create",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(template),
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (data) { } 
});
```

However, the `[HttpPost]` `Create ActionResult` does not even receive the `ViewModel`. I am thinking that this has something to do with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

Can someone please help me to correctly set the `exampleValue` property to be a `JSON object`, such that the object can be validated, and then returned back to the `View` if not in a valid state? If the single property cannot be serialized to a `JSON object`, is it possible to use  `ModelBinding` so that the whole `ViewModel` is posted as a `JSON object`?

Comment: Can you post an example of the template object you send via Ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

U can use a JsonFormatter such as JsonMediaTypeFormatter to Deserialize Json data according to your view model requirements(or serialize back to JSON)